# boost::asio duplicates input data in async_read

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, client-server, boost-asio

Recently, I switched to the boost::asio from the libevent, and a week later I noticed a strange thing: when I read data from the client, some of this data seems to be duplicated, as if the library doesn't have to mark it as read (or something like that).
My 'read' method looks like this:

```
void client::doRead() {
    delete readBuffer; // getting rid of old data 
    readBuffer = new SerializedBuffer((uint) READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
    readBuffer->position(0);
    asio::async_read(socket, asio::buffer(readBuffer->bytes(), READ_BUFFER_SIZE),
            asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&client::onRead, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
}

std::mutex readMutex;
void client::onRead(const asio::error_code &err, size_t nbytes) {
    if (readMutex.try_lock()) {
        if (err) {
            stop();
            return;
        }

        readBuffer->rewind();
        uint limit = (uint) nbytes;
        readBuffer->limit(limit);

        // I've lost hope
        SerializedBuffer *sbuff = new SerializedBuffer(limit);
        memcpy(sbuff->bytes(), readBuffer->bytes(), limit);
        sbuff->limit(limit);

        // that's where I'm checking what I get
        Utils::print(sbuff->bytes(), limit);

        onReceivedData(shared_from_this(), sbuff);
        delete sbuff;
        readMutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

For example, client sent data like this:

```
<< 38
<< FA 6F 73 ... BE BB
```

(two writes of a binary data)

But the server received:

```
>> FA
>> FA 6F 73 ... BE BB
```

'Where did the byte '38' disappear?' - I ask myself.
This happens with a probability of 10% after 3-4 packets were successfully transferred.

Comment: Re. the reported issue: it cannot be reproduced given your code. There's likely undefined behaviour (if I had to guess, you have a race condition that uses a stale pointer to a `SerializedBuffer` that has since been reused for the new instance). That's a lot of guess work, but it's the best we can do.

Comment: @sehe well, now I'll definitely solve the problem!

Answer (score 5):

There are too many anti-patterns going on.

- don't use `new`/`delete`
- don't use non-RAII locks (`try_lock` is a smell)
- if you use `try_lock`, handle all return values! (And use `std::adopt_lock`/`std::defer_lock`)
- don't use locks with asynchronous operations (`asio::io_service::strand` is what you need)
- don't do your own buffer implementation unless you need. In particular, when you have a nice abstraction like `asio::const_buffer*` why type `print` to take a raw pointer + size? Boost has `string_ref`, standard library has `string_view` and Asio has the `asio::buffer` facility.
- if your class has `position()`/`position(uint)` members then it's a quasi-class and you should probably just expose the member field.
- just make `READ_BUFFER_SIZE`  unsigned (e.g. `#define RBS 1024u`)
- make `SerializedBuffer` properly initialize, instead of requiring `readBuffer->position(0);` immediately after constructing

### SSCCE

I know you're using non-boost Asio, but allow me (since you do use boost/bind):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f506adcd5efa3ef7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

namespace Utils {
    void print(char const* data, size_t n) {
        for (auto it=data; it <data+n; ++it) {
            int v = static_cast<uint8_t>(*it);
            std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << v << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

struct SerializedBuffer {
    std::vector<char> _buf;
    size_t _pos = 0;

    size_t position() const { return _pos; }
    void position(size_t n) { _pos = n; }
    void rewind() { position(0); }
    char* bytes() { return _buf.data(); }

    size_t limit() { return _buf.size(); }
    void limit(size_t n) { _buf.resize(n); }

    SerializedBuffer(size_t n) : _buf(n) {}
};

struct client : boost::enable_shared_from_this<client> {
    client(boost::asio::io_service& svc) : _svc(svc), socket(_svc) {
        socket.connect({boost::asio::ip::address{}, 6767});
    }
    void doRead();

    SerializedBuffer* readBuffer = nullptr;
    void onRead(boost::system::error_code err, size_t nbytes);

    void stop() {
        socket.get_io_service().stop();
    }

    void onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client> This, SerializedBuffer* sb) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": ";
        Utils::print(sb->bytes(), sb->limit());

        doRead();
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::io_service& _svc;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
};

void client::doRead() {
    delete readBuffer; // getting rid of old data 
    readBuffer = new SerializedBuffer((uint) READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
    readBuffer->position(0);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(readBuffer->bytes(), READ_BUFFER_SIZE),
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&client::onRead, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
}

std::mutex readMutex;
void client::onRead(boost::system::error_code err, size_t nbytes) {
    if (readMutex.try_lock()) {
        if (err) {
            stop();
            return;
        }

        readBuffer->rewind();
        uint limit = (uint) nbytes;
        readBuffer->limit(limit);

        // I've lost hope
        SerializedBuffer *sbuff = new SerializedBuffer(limit);
        memcpy(sbuff->bytes(), readBuffer->bytes(), limit);
        sbuff->limit(limit);

        // that's where I'm checking what I get
        Utils::print(sbuff->bytes(), limit);

        onReceivedData(shared_from_this(), sbuff);
        delete sbuff;
        readMutex.unlock();
    }
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    auto c = boost::make_shared<client>(svc);
    c->doRead();

    svc.run();
}
```

Which when run against a mock server like

```
(printf '\x38\n'; sleep 3; printf '\xFA\x6F\x73....\xBE\xBB\n') | netcat -l -p 6767
```

Prints

```
38 0a 
void client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, SerializedBuffer*): 38 0a 
fa 6f 73 2e 2e 2e 2e be bb 0a 
void client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, SerializedBuffer*): fa 6f 73 2e 2e 2e 2e be bb 0a
```

And of course I didn't fix the memory leaks:

```
==31732==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff150beffb0 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.3+0xc7fb0)
    #1 0x41fa58 in client::doRead() /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:63
    #2 0x44150f in client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, SerializedBuffer*) /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:53
    #3 0x4200a6 in client::onRead(boost::system::error_code, unsigned long) /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:90
    #4 0x454ff0 in void boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>::call<boost::shared_ptr<client>, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>(boost::shared_ptr<client>&, void const*, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) const /home/sehe/
    #5 0x4543bc in void boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>::operator()<boost::shared_ptr<client> >(boost::shared_ptr<client>&, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long) const /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:286
    #6 0x4532a4 in void boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<client> >, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::rrlist2<boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long 
    #7 0x452465 in void boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<client> >, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >::operator()<boost::system::error_code const&, unsigne
    #8 0x44f361 in boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi:
    #9 0x456eb4 in boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost::_
    #10 0x456dd6 in void boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio
    #11 0x456d3a in void boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, bo
    #12 0x456a6e in void boost::asio::detail::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boo
    #13 0x4565ed in void boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, bo
    #14 0x455cdb in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, b
    #15 0x426f4b in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
    #16 0x432dd5 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/impl/epol
    #17 0x426f4b in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
    #18 0x4373af in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/impl/task
    #19 0x435739 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:149
    #20 0x438804 in boost::asio::io_service::run() /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
    #21 0x42024e in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:102
    #22 0x7ff14f09d82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)

Indirect leak of 1024 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff150beffb0 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.3+0xc7fb0)
    #1 0x4537d4 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/6/ext/new_allocator.h:104
    #2 0x4527bb in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::allocate(std::allocator<char>&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/alloc_traits.h:436
    #3 0x451284 in std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:170
    #4 0x4514ea in std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:185
    #5 0x44d8be in std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:136
    #6 0x4494fc in std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:280
    #7 0x440f09 in SerializedBuffer::SerializedBuffer(unsigned long) /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:33
    #8 0x41fa88 in client::doRead() /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:63
    #9 0x44150f in client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, SerializedBuffer*) /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:53
    #10 0x4200a6 in client::onRead(boost::system::error_code, unsigned long) /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:90
    #11 0x454ff0 in void boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>::call<boost::shared_ptr<client>, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>(boost::shared_ptr<client>&, void const*, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) const /home/sehe
    #12 0x4543bc in void boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>::operator()<boost::shared_ptr<client> >(boost::shared_ptr<client>&, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long) const /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:286
    #13 0x4532a4 in void boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<client> >, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::rrlist2<boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long
    #14 0x452465 in void boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, client, boost::system::error_code, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<client> >, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >::operator()<boost::system::error_code const&, unsign
    #15 0x44f361 in boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi
    #16 0x456eb4 in boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost::
    #17 0x456dd6 in void boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio
    #18 0x456d3a in void boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, bo
    #19 0x456a6e in void boost::asio::detail::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boo
    #20 0x4565ed in void boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, bo
    #21 0x455cdb in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, b
    #22 0x426f4b in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
    #23 0x432dd5 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/impl/epol
    #24 0x426f4b in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
    #25 0x4373af in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/impl/task
    #26 0x435739 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:149
    #27 0x438804 in boost::asio::io_service::run() /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
    #28 0x42024e in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:102
    #29 0x7ff14f09d82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1056 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

### Fixing the memory allocations

Just use `unique_ptr` and *move* ownership if required:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE 1024u

namespace Utils {
    void print(char const* data, size_t n) {
        for (auto it=data; it <data+n; ++it) {
            int v = static_cast<uint8_t>(*it);
            std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << v << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

struct SerializedBuffer {
    std::vector<char> _buf;
    size_t _pos = 0;

    size_t position() const { return _pos; }
    void position(size_t n) { _pos = n; }
    void rewind() { position(0); }
    char* bytes() { return _buf.data(); }

    size_t limit() { return _buf.size(); }
    void limit(size_t n) { _buf.resize(n); }

    SerializedBuffer(size_t n) : _buf(n) {}
};

struct client : boost::enable_shared_from_this<client> {
    client(boost::asio::io_service& svc) : _svc(svc), socket(_svc) {
        socket.connect({boost::asio::ip::address{}, 6767});
    }
    void doRead();

    void onRead(boost::system::error_code err, size_t nbytes);

    void stop() {
        socket.get_io_service().stop();
    }

    void onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client> This, std::unique_ptr<SerializedBuffer> sb) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": ";
        Utils::print(sb->bytes(), sb->limit());

        doRead();
    }

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<SerializedBuffer> readBuffer;
    boost::asio::io_service& _svc;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
};

void client::doRead() {
    readBuffer.reset(new SerializedBuffer(READ_BUFFER_SIZE));
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(readBuffer->bytes(), READ_BUFFER_SIZE),
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&client::onRead, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
}

void client::onRead(boost::system::error_code err, size_t nbytes) {
    if (err) {
        stop();
        return;
    }

    readBuffer->rewind();
    readBuffer->limit(nbytes);

    onReceivedData(shared_from_this(), std::move(readBuffer));
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    auto c = boost::make_shared<client>(svc);
    c->doRead();

    svc.run();
}
```

Prints:

```
$ ./sotest 
void client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, std::unique_ptr<SerializedBuffer>): 38 0a fa 6f 73 2e 2e 2e 2e be bb 0a
```

Or

```
$ ./sotest 
void client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, std::unique_ptr<SerializedBuffer>): 38 0a 
void client::onReceivedData(boost::shared_ptr<client>, std::unique_ptr<SerializedBuffer>): fa 6f 73 2e 2e 2e 2e be bb 0a
```

Depending on timing.

Comment: [Live sample now works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f506adcd5efa3ef7). Added a bonus take that replaces the `GlorifiedBuffer` class with `std::vector` and show how to leverage `string_ref` e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34573e53c40dab28

Comment: That code is from my server, so I use async_accept to accept clients, do I still need to use unique io_service for each client?

Comment: thank you. My system is more complex, than I explain in my question, so I can't use unique_ptr. I noticed, that somehow some part of data in the readBuffer got replaced by something. I need to go deeper...
Again: my problem only occurs after a couple of packets has been sent.

Comment: Again: your problem is that you didn't distill a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. Don't blame me for actually making up 60% of the code that you didn't include. And yes, you can use a smart pointer.

Comment: Don't be sad, but Your code did not bring anything new into my code, except wrapping the buffer in a unique pointer (it's not necessary) and getting rid of the mutex (not necessary too).

Comment: Here's with a `server` class that accepts incoming connections, as well as renaming `client` to `connection` (so that this makes sense). [server](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/230745f6bc6fb5ba)

Comment: @VladMarkushin I /am/ sad because you're not realizing this is what makes it impossible to help. You pride yourself in the fact that I didn't make up anything new. However, the trouble is, you didn't show the part that creates the problem. And yes, all the code smells gives me a good reason to assume that indeed you [create UB elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212576/boostasio-duplicates-input-data-in-async-read#comment77397477_45212576). YOU show the code I'm making up differently. Then we can help.